# Automapper Member mapping on codition SeemsConvoluted

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to find the correct way to implement this.

```
 return isOptionTrue? Mapper.Map<Context>(myObject) : Mapper.Map<ReplayContext>(myObject);
```

Context has all the fields I actually need.

```
public class ContextReplay: Context
{
    //This class is a work around to trick Automapper
}
```

Then of course the mappings

```
Mapper.CreateMap<myObject, Context>()
      .ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.Id))
      .ForMember(x => x.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.Name));
      .ForMember(x => x.Important, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.NormalProp));


Mapper.CreateMap<myObject, ContextReplay>()
      .ForMember(x => x.WellId, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.Id))
      .ForMember(x => x.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.Name));
      .ForMember(x => x.Important, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.ReplayProp));
```

As you can see, I really want:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<myObject, Context>()
      .ForMember(x => x.WellId, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.Id))
      .ForMember(x => x.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.Name));
      .ForMember(x => x.Important, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => isOptionTrue? y.NormProp: y.ReplayProp));
```

For questions: Yes i have an empty sublcass, becuase I cont have two unique MyObject to Context mappings. This whole thing seems like a super hacky work around. I can't imagine they really don't support something like this, but im at a loss. I have no idea how to get my bool passed along with it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a way to use a `opt.Condition` here, but I'm not at a system with Automapper to test. https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Conditional-mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps my imagination is limited, but personally I find "auto mapping" to be of limited use, except when mapping between two "identical" classes. Wouldn't it be more straight-forward, faster, and easier to maintain the following bit of code?

```
var context = new Context {
    WellId = myObject.Id,
    Name = myObject.Name,
    Important = (isOptionTrue ? myObject.NormProp : myObject.ReplayProp)
};
```

Comment: Absolutely. Unquestionably. However I'm working with what I've been given, and its non-trivial to rip out. I'm a firm believer in consistency, and if you are going to change something, change it everywhere. Also, of course, its a much longer list of properties, and I have to implement the solution to this problem three times.'

Comment: Can you extend `myObjectType` by adding the `isOptionTrue` property, or preferably add a sub-class that has this property on it?

Comment: Actually, I decided to go ahead and break pattern here, I finally got tired of fighting it. It turned out i could pull Automapper out of this 'project' and isolate it to a different corner of the solution that is used on start up.